# Compiles vdproj and MsBuild error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, setup-project

I have **Visual Studio 2013**, and a *Windows Forms application* and *Libraries projects*.

I have installed **Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Installer Projects**.
I have created Setup Project.

Compiling using Visual Studio 2013 is OK. 
Now, I use a BAT Script:

```
msbuild.exe ..\Installers\Setup.Apps.Utiles\Setup.Apps.Utiles.vdproj /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=Build2.log
```

I get the following error:

> error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root
>   level is invalid

The logfile **Build2.log** contains:

```
Compilación iniciada a las 28/02/2017 8:56:40.
__________________________________________________
Proyecto "C:\TFS\COMPANY.CRETA\Installers\Setup.Apps.Utiles\Setup.Apps.Utiles.vdproj" (Rebuild destino(s)):

C:\TFS\COMPANY.CRETA\Installers\Setup.Apps.Utiles\Setup.Apps.Utiles.vdproj(1,1): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Compilación del proyecto "Setup.Apps.Utiles.vdproj" terminada -- ERROR.

ERROR al compilar.

C:\TFS\COMPANY.CRETA\Installers\Setup.Apps.Utiles\Setup.Apps.Utiles.vdproj(1,1): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
    0 Advertencia(s)
    1 Errores

Tiempo transcurrido 00:00:00.29
```

Note: I don't use TFVC, Git neither VCS or DVCS.

any suggestions?

Comment: I see that vdproj file is an MSI creation project for earlier VS version, but `msbuild` needs solution/project (cs/vbproj) file to compile with. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx for `msbuild` command details.